# Directed Acyclic Graph, complexity, performance, versatility benefits of various implementations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm

When implementing a `Directed Acyclic Graph`, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph, also known as a DAG, there are a few ways that come to mind in terms of the internal representation of it.

The ones that pop into my mind are:

- A map `V -> { E }`, i.e: `Map<V, Set<E>>`.
- A tree where each node has a set or list of children (outgoing edges), i.e:

`class DAG<V, W> {
        List<Node<V, W>> roots;
        static class Node<V, W> {
            List<Node<V, W> successors;
            W weight; // optionally...
            V value;
        }
    }`

- A List> where Node contains the V, and a list of outgoing edges List
- A List and a List
- < insert more >

What are the pros & cons of the various data-structures outlined in terms of complexity, performance, versatility when it comes to common DAG algorithms and tasks such as:

- Computing the in & out degree of one or all vertrices.
- Finding the shortest path.
- Computing the Minimum Spanning Tree (MST).
- Retrieving all vertrices
- Retrieving all edges.
- Adding a vertrice.
- Adding an edge.
- Checking for cycles on addition of edges.
- < insert more >

What internal representation would you use, and if you were to combine them, how would you do so and why?

Comment: The pros and cons depend on the actual problem space of the thing you are trying to solve. You'll need to decide which of the operations matter most, and pick the implementation that gives the best solution for a specific problem. The implementation you pick for a large, complex, but primarily static DAG that is just repeatedly referenced in various ways might be quite different than what you would pick to maintain a highly dynamic always changing DAG...

Comment: All true, but I'm wondering what the impact of the various implementations for various operations. For example: in the documentation of ArrayList & LinkedList (java specifically), the complexity of each operation is listed - and you can then compare them with each other to find what you need, but there's nothing similar I've found for implementations of a DAG. In order to pick an implementation that has the best solution for the specific problem without having to redo it all, it is nice to have a table of comparison...

Comment: As twalberg points out, this is all highly dependent on the application (and what your DAG looks like).  A particular implementation might be great for one application and poor for another.  I personally like storing graphs (directed or not) as adjacency matrices.  That makes a lot of calculations very easy.  BUT, it takes up a huge amount of memory if your graph is large (many vertices) and "wastes" a lot of memory if your graph is sparse (not very many edges).  Some times the A-matrix is great.  Other times, it is not.